# How to get RadioButtonList ListItems to display text in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

The Code Code below is the section that binds to my asp.net gridview. But I can't get none of the ListItems to display text values even when using Text="Male" or Text="Female". The whole grid is bound to a List of objects that a populate from a database. And each grid column is bound to a datacolumn from the database. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:RadioButtonList  ID="rlGender"  runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical"  SelectedValue='<%#  bool.Parse(Eval("GenderS").ToString()) %>'><asp:ListItem   Value="True" >Male</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Value="False">Female</asp:ListItem></asp:RadioButtonList>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>                    
  <asp:RadioButtonList   ID="rlGender"   runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" SelectedValue='<%#  bool.Parse(Eval("GenderS").ToString()) %>'><asp:ListItem   Value="True">Male</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem  Value="False">Female</asp:ListItem></asp:RadioButtonList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You can't have same ID in edit template. Try changing ID.  But what's point having same control in edit template and item template?

Comment: I Don't really know the exact difference between the two templates, but what I want is for the user to be able to view the current gender of the employee. And if they want to edit it they must be able to select a different gender. The only problem I have is showing the text next to each Gender List Item...?

Answer (score 0):

In **ItemTemplate** better to keep value in control which doesn't require editing. When grid goes into edit mode then control present in **EditItemTemplate** would be visible. There you could change the value. The changing should be saved in the datasource by handling gridview rowupdating event.

`Label` could be use to display readonly text in the `ItemTemplate`. In the `Text` property of Label you could directly refer to column which gives text either `Male` or `Female`.

Èxample would be something like that:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
    <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:RadioButtonList  ID="rlGender"  runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical"  SelectedValue='<%#  bool.Parse(Eval("GenderS").ToString()) %>'>
            <asp:ListItem  Value="True" Text = "Male" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="False" Text="Female" />
         </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblGender" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GenderS").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>                   

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

or use **ItemTemplate** to always display `RadioButtonList`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:RadioButtonList  ID="rlGender"  runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical"  SelectedValue='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("GenderS").ToString()) %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Value="True" Text = "Male" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="False" Text="Female" />
         </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Ahh okay now I understand that concept. Do you know what might cause the Text to not display next to each ListItem in the Grid

Comment: Have you tried **Text** attribute of <asp:ListItem> as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Jip, and it just shows the radio buttons with the correct selection for gender but just without the text...

Comment: This might be because of `bool.Parse` for SelectedValue of RadioButtonList. Can you test by providing `SelectedValue='True'`?

Comment: Trying SelectedValue='True' gives me an error that says: The 'SelectedValue' property cannot be set declaratively.

Comment: May be True requires double quotes **SelectedValue="True"**. I am not sure but I remember RadioButtonList binding once I have done by providing Text and Value fields.